# code too large for try block in JSP

Tags: java, jsp, struts, jstl

I have a JSP page that displays a table with couple of rows.
On compile time everything looks good and in run time I get this "Code too large for try block" error. I see that I should spilt JSP and have couple of includes. But my JPS wouldnt allow since everything is with a table with couple of tr's and td's. So i cldnt split. Is there any other approach? Or how can I spilt JSP with a table?

Comment: Another approach would be to separate your java code from your presentation layer by keeping it out of your JSP.  What framework are you using: Spring? EJB?

Comment: @Jahroy..its Struts framework

Comment: my JSP doesnt have any core Java code. Its all the JSTL's in JSP.

Comment: Ok.  I'm not really familiar with the framework you're using, but I've edited the tags to encourage some more knowledgeable visitors to stop by.

Comment: How are you generating that table? Show your JSP.

Answer (score 0):

It was already said, that separation of data model and view has its advantages.

However you can use methods in a JSP too; output can also in methods be done with `%>...<%`.

JSP declarations come in `<%! ... %>`.

```
<%!

private void f(JspWriter out) throws Exception {
    out.println("hello");
}


private void tr(String a, String b) throws Exception {
   %><tr><td><%= a %></td><td><%= b %></td></tr>
   <%
}

%>
<%
    f(out);
%>
<table>
<%
    tr("good day", "bonan tagon");
    tr("good night", "bonan nokton");
%>
</table>
```

Comment: What is the use of having these tags? What code should I put in there?

Comment: Declarations, like functions so you can split your jsp into smaller parts. Maybe repeatable functions for outputing a TR.

Comment: But isnt the scriptlet in jsp converted to java and palced inside service() method? wont it give the same result. I have no idea. can someone leme know.

Comment: No the declarations are placed inside the class braces.